# UINavigationView - Stop a video from playing when back pressed

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationView where I push on a ViewController containing a WebView with a YouTube video. When the video is run, then the back button is pressed on the UINavigationView, the sound of the video continues to play.

How do I stop the video playing in the WebView when it is no longer visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your web view is getting deallocated when the view controller goes away.